# Wrap, clone и проблема с клонированием и шириной

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть вот такая задачка.

А проблема такая: есть у нас `<input>`, его нужно обернуть в `<div>`, потом еще раз в `<div>` и еще раз в `<div>`. Потом предпоследний `<div>` клонировать и вставить в последний `<div>`.

По сути, должно выйти:

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='info'>
        <div>
            <input>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='info'>
        <div>
            <input>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

По сути, ничего сложного, но таким образом не работает:

```
var $wrapper = $("<div>").addClass("wrapper");
var $wrapper_two = $("<div class='info'><div></div></div>").appendTo($wrapper);

$("input").wrap($wrapper);

$wrapper_two.clone().appendTo($wrapper);
```

И ширину не получается узнать:

```
console.log($wrapper.width());  // => 0
```

Потестить: http://jsfiddle.net/1w08fhpv/6/

Comment: Может,
 
    var $wrapper = $("<div></div>").addClass("wrapper");

Comment: а что вообще выходит?

Comment: @OlegUP гляньте пример, я ссылку указал: http://jsfiddle.net/1w08fhpv/6/

Comment: Не понимаю, в чем проблема, как будто элемент кешируется. Пока решил проблему, получаем родителя от input.

Comment: Никто не знает, в чем проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При wrap объект клонируется.

всему виной вот эта строка

[`wrap = jQuery( html, this[ 0 ].ownerDocument ).eq( 0 ).clone( true );`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/c62486fb4cb18fdb7dc5807231c964ed82ee6482/src/wrap.js#L18)

что именно заставило разработчика сделать тут клонирование я не нашел. вот коммит в котором это встречается первый раз

[8a4a1edf **Initial import**](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/8a4a1edf047f2c272f663866eb7b5fcd644d65b3#diff-d7afd4e7a018671200c73c996b76957aR130)

тут на всякий случай демо с парентом без привязки к структуре wrapper2 http://jsfiddle.net/1w08fhpv/7/

[грязно пропатченный wrap и wrapAll](http://jsfiddle.net/1w08fhpv/11/)

и наконец, ["нормальное" решение](http://jsfiddle.net/1w08fhpv/12/)

Comment: Я решил так: во .wrapper всё обернул и через parents() просто опять получил этот .wapper.